# Петербуржская норма произношения

Tags: фонетика

Недавно
 в комментариях обнаружил диалог, где писалось, что при фонетической 
записи на русском правильно было бы не "ш**э**рстяной", а 
"ш**ы**рстяной". В литературе для школьников, что я недавно рассматривал
 звук э склонный к и, тоже не упоминался. Однако во времена моей учебы в
 университете, нам объясняли, что в русском языке существует две нормы 
произношения: икающая московская и экающая петербуржская. Причем, 
например для Вологды, менее выраженое аканье петербуржцев, звучит на 
слух естественнее. В связи с этим два вопроса:

1. *По-прежнему ли 
   петербуржское произношение является нормой?*
2. *Засчитают ли школьнику за ошибку, написание при фонетическом разборе звука [(эи)] вместо [(иэ)]*?

---

Дописал сами вопросы, из-за глюка они почему-то не отобразились сразу.

Comment: Я произношу "шэрсть" и не произношу "шырсть".

Comment: Я  произношу  "шэрсть",  но  "шырстяной".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В русском языке гласные в безударных слогах подвергаются редукции независимо от места проживания носителя языка. Поэтому звука Э в безударной позиции нет, только под ударением. Но коренные москвичи произнесут нечто среднее между Ы и Э, а петербуржцы произнесут Ы. Литературной нормой признается московское произношение. Школьники о разных фонетических школах не знают. Но они обязательно должны знать, что произношение ударного гласного и безударного (только И, Ы, У не редуцируются) различаются и Э в безударной позиции быть не может.

Comment: С одной стороны, "в русском языке гласные в безударных слогах подвергаются редукции [независимо от места проживания носителя языка]", а с другой стороны, "только И, Ы, У не редуцируются".

P.S. Я не возражаю, чтобы школьник Tagirix, желающий получить помощь от "уважаемых филологов", прочёл ответ участника Ларf.

Comment: Ну что делать... Так уж сложилось, что И, Ы, У не редуцируются. Но, конечно, логичнее было бы об этом упомянуть раньше.

Comment: Если желаете, можете добавить [для Tagirix'а от имени "уважаемых филологов"], что "правильные русские" произносят звуки [о] и [э] только под ударением.
 
P.S. Например:

1) в слове "золото" звук [о] произносится на первом слоге,

2) в слове "болото" звук [о] произносится на втором слоге,

3) в слове "молоко" звук [о] произносится на третьем слоге.

Answer (score 2):

В старомосковском произношении гласные О, А, Е, Ы после Ж,Ш,Ц (в первом предударном слоге) произносились в соответствии с мягкой редукцией,  то есть как звук ы(е): [жые]ра, [шые]гать.

Однако со временем нормы менялись, и  произношение [ые] после [ш], [ж] достаточно устойчиво сохраняется только в случаях соответствия этого гласного гласным [о] и [е]: ш(ые)ренга, но ж(Λ)ра.

В то же время  вариант (ые) сохраняется  в ряде слов, например: ж(ые)леть. Интересно, что в этом случае орфоэпический словарь указывает особую норму произношения, в то время как на слово ш(ые)рстяной таких указаний нет (то есть это общепринятый вариант).

Такое "новомосковское" произношение  является нормой русского литературного языка.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (КРАТКИЕ СВЕДЕНИЯ О РЕДУКЦИИ)

Редукция -  это качественное и количественное изменение безударных гласных.  Когда мы говорим, что гласные не редуцируются (И, Ы, У), это означает, что они не редуцируются качественно, но при этом они всегда редуцируются количественно. Например, нам приходится проверять окончания глаголов АТ/ЯТ или УТ/ЮТ, так как в послеударном слоге звук У произносится очень кратко.

УПРОЩЕННАЯ СХЕМА РЕДУКЦИИ (1-ая и 2-ая степень):

После твердых согласных:  1) А, О  →  Λ → Ъ     2) Ы, Е → Ы (ЫЭ) →Ъ.

После мягких согласных:  Е, И, Я   → И(ИЭ)→   Ь .

После твердых шипящих:  О, Е  → Ы (ЫЭ) → Ъ , иногда А  → Ы (ЫЭ) .

И ответы на вопросы

1) Литературной нормой всегда считалось московское произношение.

2) При фонетическом разборе ошибку обязательно засчитают. Там вообще все очень строго, надо дополнительно учитывать предударные и послеударные слоги.

Comment: Презаумно.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, гласные и,ы,у не редуцируются. А нормой считается московское произношение.

Comment: Очень интересная статья. http://dljatebja.ru/orfoslova/Vvedenie/Moskovskoe_i_leningradskoe_proiznoshenie.html